# Yii2, настройка конфига с запросом в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, yii2, foreach, config

Структуру знаю еще плохо, но возник такой вопрос, возможно ли это вообще? Вопрос имеет отношение к роутингу, создал в админ-панели раздел заведения новых страниц (СЕО описания к разделам соответствующие имени контроллера) и дабы не прописывать в будущем каждый раз эти настройки, этим модулем хотел генерировать в конфиге маршрутизацию перебором в foreach.

На данный момент конфиг выглядит так:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:[\w-]+>/view/<slug:[\w-]+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:[\w-]+>/cat/<slug:[\w-]+>' => '<controller>/cat',

            'admin' => 'admin/system/default',
            ['pattern' => 'admin','route' => 'admin/system/default','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/settings' => 'admin/system/settings',
            'admin/settings/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/settings/<action>',
            'admin/settings/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/settings/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/settings','route' => 'admin/system/settings/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/settings/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/settings/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/settings/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/settings/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/modules' => 'admin/system/modules',
            'admin/modules/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/modules/<action>',
            'admin/modules/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/modules/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/modules','route' => 'admin/system/modules/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/modules/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/modules/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/modules/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/modules/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/system' => 'admin/system/system',
            'admin/system/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/system/<action>',
            'admin/system/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/system/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/system','route' => 'admin/system/system/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/system/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/system/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/system/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/system/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/logs' => 'admin/system/logs',
            'admin/logs/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/logs/<action>',
            'admin/logs/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/logs/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/logs','route' => 'admin/system/logs/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/logs/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/logs/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/logs/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/logs/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/tags' => 'admin/system/tags',
            'admin/tags/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/tags/<action>',
            'admin/tags/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/tags/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/tags','route' => 'admin/system/tags/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/tags/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/tags/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/tags/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/tags/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/user' => 'admin/system/user',
            'admin/user/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/user/<action>',
            'admin/user/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/user/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/user','route' => 'admin/system/user/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/user/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/user/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/user/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/user/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/role' => 'admin/system/role',
            'admin/role/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/role/<action>',
            'admin/role/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/role/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/role','route' => 'admin/system/role/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/role/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/role/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/role/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/role/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/permission' => 'admin/system/permission',
            'admin/permission/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/permission/<action>',
            'admin/permission/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/permission/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/permission','route' => 'admin/system/permission/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/permission/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/permission/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/permission/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/permission/<action>','suffix' => '/',],

            'admin/rule' => 'admin/system/rule',
            'admin/rule/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/system/rule/<action>',
            'admin/rule/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/system/rule/<action>',
            ['pattern' => 'admin/rule','route' => 'admin/system/rule/','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/rule/<action:[\w-]+>','route' => 'admin/system/rule/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
            ['pattern' => 'admin/rule/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>','route' => 'admin/system/rule/<action>','suffix' => '/',],
        ],
    ],
```

Как отправить запрос в бд из конфига, чтобы собрать нужный мне массив?

Answer (score 0):

Такой подход не совсем правильный. Конфиг есть конфиг и оттуда не стоит лезть в БД. Я бы посмотрел в сторону предзагрузки. В общем это выглядит так:

1. Создаем модуль
2. Добавляем его в секцию bootstrap в конфиге
3. В модуле делаем запрос к БД, формируем необходимый массив
4. Добавляем правила в урлменеджер динамически

В итоге получаем аккуратный конфиг и отдельно обработку и добавление правил к урлам. Тут чуть [подробнее по добавлению правил динамически](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-routing#adding-rules).

Тут [немного о предзагрузке](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-bootstrapping).